# Binding Textbox.Text to Custom Control DP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I need a custom control (CC) where the Text property of the textbox in the CC can be binded to a DependancyProperty on the CC.

I also tried to bind the textbox.text with templatebinding.

I tried almost everything i can think of, what to do? :

Custom Control in Generics:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextboxCC}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextboxCC}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding NText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TextboxCC}}}"  />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

CC.cs

```
public class TextboxCC : Control
{
    public string NText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NText", typeof(string), typeof(TextboxCC), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    static TextboxCC()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextboxCC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextboxCC)));
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

The Label is just there to check if the value is changed in Mainwindow.Test

```
<local:TextboxCC NText="{Binding Test,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Test,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206"/>
```

Mainwindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _test;

    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();this.DataContext = this;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext?

Comment: Yes i did it in Design but here i added it in code now.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your code works fine for me. Do you perhaps need the binding to be updated on every key stroke in the CCs TextBox?

Comment: Yes when i type in the Textbox the Label should update directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a binding on a TextBox's `Text` property is only updated (in source direction) when the control loses focus. If you want it to be updated each time the text changes, you can set the binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NText,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TextboxCC},
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement something like this:

```
void ExtendedCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!chk_IsChanging)
            this.IsCheckedReal = "X";                      

    }

    public string IsCheckedReal
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IsCheckedRealProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckedRealProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedRealProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckedReal", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(IsCheckedRealChanged));

    private static void IsCheckedRealChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.NewValue.Equals("X") || e.NewValue.Equals("Y"))
        {
            ((ExtendedCheckBox)o).IsChecked = true;
        }
        else if (e.NewValue.Equals("") || e.NewValue.Equals("N"))
        {
            ((ExtendedCheckBox)o).IsChecked = false;
        }


    }
```

I want the behaviour that on checking of checkbox, I want a "X" mark in my model property.

So I have created a dependency property `IsCheckedRealProperty` that I will bind like this:

```
chk.SetBinding(ExtendedCheckBox.IsCheckedRealProperty, binding);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the implementation of your dependency property to this, and your code will work as it is. The textbox is updated on lost focus.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "NText", typeof (string), typeof (TextboxCC), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

   public string NText
   {
       get { return (string) GetValue(NTextProperty); }
       set { SetValue(NTextProperty, value); }
   }
```

Comment: `default(string)` is `null`. Hence your code does the same as that in the question.

Comment: Yes my mistake, I got fooled by an error while trying this code and recreated the dependency property with ReSharper.